# How to automatically start scrolling a parent scrollable widget when the child scrollable reaches the top in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, scroll, nestedscrollview, customscrollview

It seems quite natural and maybe even expected, but I still haven't found anything that may help.
I have a ScrollablePositionedList (almost the same as a ListView) inside another scrollable widget (parent) (I've tried both CustomScrollView and ListView, even NestedScrollView) and I want to make it look so that when I scroll to the top of the child scrollable and still swipe I actually scroll in the parent scrollable.
Any help would be most welcome, thank you!